# VBA Function or Macro to Move Selected Message(s) to Folder of Conversation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I organize all my Outlook messages as conversations. I'm looking for a function to move the currently selected message(s) from the inbox to their respective folders.

For example, if I have an email conversation called "Weekly Status Report" which has been filed into the folder "Engineering" and I receive a reply in my inbox, I'd like to run the macro and have the reply moved to the "Engineering" folder.

I'm using Outlook in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

My initial attempt at solving the problem sort of works, but I'd like to:

1. Add functionality for non-mailitem objects;
2. Clean up the `For Each` loop by first checking if all the root items for the conversation point to the same table. If they don't, I'd like to prompt the user with the dialog to select the desired folder.

Here’s my current attempt:

```
Sub moveMailToConversationFolder()

    Dim olNs As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim selectedItem As Object
    Dim item As Outlook.mailItem ' Mail Item
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder ' Current Item's Folder
    Dim conversation As Outlook.conversation ' Get the conversation
    ' Dim ItemsTable As Outlook.table ' Conversation table object
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Dim mailparent As Object

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' On Error GoTo MsgErr
    ' // Must Selected Item.
    Set selectedItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

    ' // If Item = a MailItem.
    If TypeOf selectedItem Is Outlook.mailItem Then
        Set item = selectedItem
        Set conversation = item.GetConversation

        If Not IsNull(conversation) Then
            ' Set ItemsTable = conversation.GetTable

            ' MsgBox conversation.GetRootItems.Count

            For Each mailItem In conversation.GetRootItems ' Items in the conversation.
                If TypeOf mailItem Is Outlook.mailItem Then
                    Set folder = mailItem.Parent
                    item.move GetFolder(folder.FolderPath)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.folder

    Dim TestFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolder_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If

    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set TestFolder = Application.Session.Folders.item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not TestFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = TestFolder.Folders
            Set TestFolder = SubFolders.item(FoldersArray(i))
            If TestFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolder = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Return the TestFolder
    Set GetFolder = TestFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolder_Error:
    Set GetFolder = Nothing
Exit Function

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar script that may help.

My use case is a bit different - I manually select items in a custom view and then run the script from a toolbar button. (I find that Conversations are not properly tracked, plus sometimes a conversation diverges into different projects.)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Sub MoveToFirstFolder()
  Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace, oSelection As Outlook.Selection
  Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim oItem As Object, i As Integer

  Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  Set oSelection = oNamespace.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  If oSelection.Count < 2 Then Exit Sub

  Set oFolder = getFirstNonDefaultFolder(oSelection)
  If oFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  ' move items
  For i = 1 To oSelection.Count
    Set oItem = oSelection.Item(i)
    If Not oItem.Parent = oFolder Then
      oSelection.Item(i).Move oFolder
    End If
  Next i
End Sub

Private Function getFirstNonDefaultFolder(oSelection As Outlook.Selection) As Outlook.Folder
  Dim oItem As Object
  Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
  Dim i As Integer

  ' get folder
  For i = 1 To oSelection.Count
    Set oFolder = oSelection.Item(i).Parent
    Debug.Print ">" & oFolder.FullFolderPath
    If Not isDefaultFolder(oFolder) Then
      Set getFirstNonDefaultFolder = oFolder
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next i
End Function

Private Function isDefaultFolder(oFolder As Outlook.Folder) As Boolean
  Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim defaultFolders, fldrNum

  isDefaultFolder = False

  defaultFolders = Array( _
    olFolderInbox, olFolderSentMail, _
    olFolderDrafts, _
    olFolderDeletedItems, olFolderJunk, _
    olFolderOutbox, _
    olFolderCalendar, _
    olFolderContacts, olFolderSuggestedContacts, _
    olFolderNotes, _
    olFolderTasks, olFolderToDo, _
    olFolderJournal, _
    olFolderConflicts, olFolderLocalFailures, olFolderServerFailures, olFolderSyncIssues, _
    olFolderManagedEmail, olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders _
  )

  Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  On Error Resume Next  ' Non-existant DefaultFolders cause errors
  For Each fldrNum In defaultFolders
    If oFolder = oNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(fldrNum) Then
      If Err.Number Then
        Err.Clear
      Else
        isDefaultFolder = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next fldrNum
End Function
```